# ipv4 websites hardly reachable with a particular wi-fi network on a particular device wereas ipv6 ones work fine

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection

Can hardly reach most high profile websites (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com, https://github.com) under a **particular Wi-Fi network with the particular laptop** regardless of the browser used. However, Google-affiliated sites (e.g. https://google.com, https://youtube.com) work without issue.

Had not experienced any issues before with the laptop using any other Wi-Fi networks around Europe (airports, coffee shops, other home networks, you name it).

Any other devices around (Windows laptop, iPad, iPhone, Android phone) have absolutely no issue displaying any of the troubled websites above using the very same Wi-Fi network.

So it seems there's some misalignment between the laptop and the network.

### Setup

**Machine:** Dell XPS-13-9360 laptop

**Wireless adapter:**

```sh
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:dc:58:19
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-77-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.173.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

**Operating system:**

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**Browsers:** Firefox 89.0.2, Chrome 91.0.4472.114

**Internet service provider:** https://www.unitymedia.de/ (Vodafone)

**Modem:** Connect box CH7465LG-LC by Compal

**Connection type:** DSL

### Diagnostics/fixes performed

**Turn it off and on again:**

Tried to

- reset the modem to factory settings
- turn modem's power off and on after some seconds
- disable modem's firewall through the admin page
- remove (forget) the connection on the laptop
- restart Network Manager

multiple times in various order.

**`ping`**

- stackoverflow.com

  ```sh
  $ ping stackoverflow.com
  PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=26 ttl=59 time=1881 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=27 ttl=59 time=857 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=28 ttl=59 time=91.0 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=29 ttl=59 time=27.4 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=30 ttl=59 time=27.4 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=31 ttl=59 time=27.7 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=32 ttl=59 time=29.1 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=33 ttl=59 time=26.0 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=34 ttl=59 time=39.5 ms
  64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=35 ttl=59 time=19.9 ms
  ^C
  --- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
  50 packets transmitted, 10 received, 80% packet loss, time 49928ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.926/302.648/1881.058/580.607 ms, pipe 2
  ```
- google.com

  ```sh
  $ ping google.com
  PING google.com(fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e)) 56 data bytes
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=30.0 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=37.2 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=23.7 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=30.4 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=118 time=26.4 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=6 ttl=118 time=23.8 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=7 ttl=118 time=46.0 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=8 ttl=118 time=16.1 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=9 ttl=118 time=45.3 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=10 ttl=118 time=18.0 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=11 ttl=118 time=22.3 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=12 ttl=118 time=28.0 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=13 ttl=118 time=20.7 ms
  64 bytes from fra24s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:831::200e): icmp_seq=14 ttl=118 time=17.3 ms
  ^C
  --- google.com ping statistics ---
  14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 13019ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.143/27.570/46.096/9.255 ms
  ```

**`tracepath`**

- stackoverflow.com

  ```sh
  $ tracepath stackoverflow.com
  1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
  1:  no reply
  ```
- google.com

  ```sh
  $ tracepath google.com
  1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.034ms pmtu 1500
  1:  2a02:908:1866:6ce0:925c:44ff:feae:f4e2                6.422ms 
  1:  2a02:908:1866:6ce0:925c:44ff:feae:f4e2                5.390ms 
  2:  2a02:908:1800:6::1                                   25.163ms 
  3:  de-fra04a-ra1-ae10-1320.fra.unity-media.net          22.841ms 
  4:  7113a-mx960-02.dar.unity-media.net                   23.385ms asymm  5 
  5:  de-fra04d-rc1-lo0-0.v6.aorta.net                     15.392ms 
  6:  no reply
  ```

#### Interestingly, modem's admin has the ability to perform `ping` and "traceroute" which both work absolutely fine (pings are short, traces go through) as if there was no problem at all.

**`iwconfig`**

```sh
wlp58s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a02:908:1866:6ce0:a0a4:8f72:2826:d298  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::5230:74d:357d:7adc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:908:1866:6ce0:d570:b754:6e12:8475  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:dc:58:19  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3276896  bytes 2709012463 (2.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1563631  bytes 613623237 (613.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**DNS**

```sh
$ systemd-resolve --status
...
Link 2 (wlp58s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      2a02:908:2:a::1
                      2a02:908:2:b::1
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      home
```

### Question

Is there anything else I can check or change to help resolve the issue?

## Update

Seems more like an ipv6 vs ipv4 issue now

```sh
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=118 time=117 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=118 time=58.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=118 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=118 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=118 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=118 time=27.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=118 time=31.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=118 time=22.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=118 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=73 ttl=118 time=1870 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=74 ttl=118 time=847 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=75 ttl=118 time=58.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=76 ttl=118 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=77 ttl=118 time=38.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=78 ttl=118 time=45.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=79 ttl=118 time=30.4 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
79 packets transmitted, 16 received, 79% packet loss, time 79539ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.114/201.907/1870.953/473.976 ms, pipe 2
```

compared to `ping google.com` above that works seamlessly.
If I disable ipv4 in the connection settings the troubled sites https://stackoverflow.com and https://github.com cease to work completely whereas https://google.com and https://gitlab.com carry on working without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the ipv4 traffic between my machine and the router is not going through well.

I managed to solve the problem by routing the ipv4 traffic through ipv6 using a public DNS64.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1278597/i-can-ping-ipv6-but-not-ipv4) helped me:

> - Click on the WiFi icon.
> - Click on `Edit Connections...`
> - Choose your SSID from the list.
> - Click on `Edit...`
> - Choose the `IPv4 Settings` tab
> - Change `Method` from `Automatic` to `Disabled`
> - Choose the `IPv6 Settings` tab
> - Change Method from `Automatic` to `Automatic, addresses only`
> - Fill in the `DNS servers` field with 2-3 DNS64 addresses

I used [TREX](http://www.trex.fi/2011/dns64.html) for DNS64 which, at the time of this writing are

```
nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::4
nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::6
```